# Pyside6 get index of dynamically created widget

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, qt-designer, pyside6

I've written this simple script(for concept understanding) to better understand how to handle/manage dynamically created combo boxes.

So in this example, we have a total of 5 dynamically created combo boxes, each containing a list of 3 variables.

When selecting any variable the function `comboFunction` is run.

What I want to understand, is:

1. How can I retrieve the index of the combo box being selected
2. The index of the variable being selected.

And print in the `comboFunction` the index of the Combobox and the variable.

---

For example in the screenshot below, I selected the combo box at index 0 and the variable at index 0.

---

[image]

```
import sys

from PySide6 import  QtWidgets


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.lists = ["1","2","3"]
        
        for i in range(5):
            
            self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
            self.combobox.addItems(self.lists)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.combobox, i,0)
            self.combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboFunction)

    def comboFunction(self):
        print("hello world")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to add its number as an attribute and read it later:

```py
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.lists = ["1", "2", "3"]

        for i in range(5):
            self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
            self.combobox.id_number = i
            self.combobox.addItems(self.lists)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.combobox, i, 0)
            self.combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboFunction)

    def comboFunction(self, idx):
        combo = self.sender()
        print(f"Selected the variable {idx} from combo {combo.id_number}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```